# wicket : how to know the current value of checkbox before submission

Tags: checkbox, wicket

Is there any way to know the current value of a checkbox in wicket before any action takes place?

`wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications()` is not useful for me, I want to know the value of the checkbox before clicking on it.

Thanks

Comment: What you're asking for is not at all clear.  Can you post some code exhibiting the issue?  I.e., where do you need this and how will you use it?

Comment: before clicking, it should still have the value of the backing model.

Comment: As above, when you create the checkbox and initialise it with a model, you can set a value in the model. I presume the default is not selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all in the server you cannot know the state of the input with out a form.

use [AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior](http://wicket.sourceforge.net/apidocs/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior.html) or [AjaxFormSubmitBehavior](http://wicket.sourceforge.net/apidocs/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.html) to attach the event to the checkbox and submit their form. with this aproach you going to submit all components inside the form, if you just want the value of the check you could use   a nested form(wicket include support for it)

Comment: thanks, what bert said is right. And the fields are all part of a form. 
So for all input fields I have to use Ajax to know the current state?

What I have noticed is that when you validate a field you can use validatable.value() to get the current value of the field. How can i get this value in the same way of the validation without using ajax? Or is this not an option?

Comment: you can use a form to content the checkbox, there its illegal in html, but you can doit in wicket because render nested form as divs and make the submit of thaht part via javascrip...
Forms can be nested. You can put a form in another form. Since HTML doesn't allow nested <form> tags, the inner forms will be rendered using the <div> tag. You have to submit the inner forms using explicit components (like Button or SubmitLink), you can't rely on implicit submit behavior
http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Form.html